# What are some optimized LAMP or LEMP stack scripts with email?

Tags: performance, deployment, lamp, shell-scripting

In the "let's try not to reinvent the wheel" perspective, I've been looking for a packaged LAMP (or LEMP) stack for some time now, not only the basic Mysql, Apache , PHP etc... but ideally stuff like APC, Postfix... basically something that would implement recognized practices & standard for security, general performance. A standard default installation that would work out of the box with all the bells & whistles that one would need to get started.

It's usually fairly easy to find the basic configurations with Apache, Mysql, PHP etc... but surprisingly difficult to find anything that goes a step further.

The [Mercury Project](http://groups.drupal.org/mercury) seems to have been absorbed by the Pantheon Project and it looks like it's not supported anymore, looking at the comments on the group's page, the install script seems out of date. There's also the [BOA](http://omega8.cc/) project that sounds excellent but goes way beyond what I'm looking for.

Linode.com has a few stackscripts but the LAMP stack doesn't implement a mailing solution ( I'm looking here for the basic notifications from the server )

And there's of course WHM/CPanel, but I've never been a fan and I'm not looking for a control panel.

Have I missed something?

Drupal optimization is a plus but not a deal breaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are installer scripts that exist for web applications and supporting services, but most of them to my knowledge are focused on the web hosting world. For example [Scriptaculous](http://softaculous.com/) and [Fantastico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastico_%28web_hosting%29), to name just two.

There are also pre-baked virtual appliances made by places like [JumpBox](http://www.jumpbox.com/), [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/), [CloudZoom](http://www.cloudzoom.com/), and [Turnkey Linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/). Those can be variously deployed to cloud providers and be up and running in mere minutes.

Perhaps you could start with some of those projects and move forward, developing something more to your own tastes.

### ...but, wait...

If after reading all of the above you're left thinking "But wait, that's not exactly what I want" that's because what you want doesn't exactly exist yet. It appears that you want something that's more specific than a generic install script (Fantastico, etc.) but not quite as heavy a a drop-in virtual appliance.

I'm sure that something closer to what you want exists. For myself, there was a time when I was working on Wordpress installations a lot and had a fancy idea to create a spectacular installation script that went an extra mile or five to lock down permissions, edit directory structures and generally clean up after the installation to make things smarter, tidier and much more secure for the Linux OS, the MySQL database server, Apache and any caching / proxies involved.

I'm sure I'm not the only one that had an idea like that, so there was likely someone who had a custom Wordpress install script that I could have used or at least learned from and mutated to my own desires. I could have turned it into quite the github project, I think.

What I'm saying is that you'll really need to get down to the grass roots level of some kind of LAMP community that focuses on the needs of those who rapidly deploy multiple servers in the use-cases that you focus on. More than likely you'll be laying down a lot of your own pipe. You'll probably want to get some core group of contributors to help you. Make it a full on FOSS project.

Then you'll be known as That Amazing FOSS Guy and you'll never lack for roses at your feet! Or, something like that...

Comment: Thanks for a detailed & fun answer! I'll have to do without the roses at my feet though as I'm nowhere near ready to undertake such a project. You're right though, nothing fits the bill. I've had a good look at the options you mentioned. Bitnami's pretty close but I'm not confident about the upgrading process. TurnkeyLinux looks great for local development or Amazon deployment, but installing it on Linode is not so straightforward. Looks like I'll have to dig deeper and get my hands dirty :)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so updating this thread from 2012 is interesting — this page still shows up in search results for LEMP stack scripts for WordPress, and beyond.

These days we now have things like Docker containers, a growing PHP Composer (Packagist) ecosystem, plus several new cloud providers with built-in setup scripts for LAMP and LEMP.

That said, there is still (and I would argue, always will be) value in lightweight Bash oriented scripts to setup niche server stacks, because:

- **Security:** the less bloat, the better security (and less maintenance)
- **Performance:** the less bloat, the faster the speed (and less items that need optimization, etc)
- **Transferable:** the less bloat, the easier to duplicate or migrate the build process
- **Usability:** the less bloat, the easier the learning curve
- *Etc.* (probably some other benefits too)

Remember: There's one thing installed on every single Unix machine in the world: **the Shell** :)

---

While there are dozens if not hundreds of basic scripts on GitHub and elsewhere, there are really only a handful of server deployment/provisioning scripts that are actively maintained, e.g.:

1. [**SlickStack**](https://slickstack.io) — Ubuntu + LEMP + WordPress + MU Plugins + CloudFlare *(Note: I'm the author)*
2. [CentminMod](https://centminmod.com) — CentOS + LEMP + tons of different options and add-ons
3. [EasyEngine](https://easyengine.io) — Ubuntu + Docker + LEMP + WordPress
4. [WordOps](https://wordops.net) — fork of EasyEngine v3 (no Docker)
5. [Webinoly](https://webinoly.com) — inspired by EasyEngine v3 but includes some non-WordPress options
6. [VPSSIM](https://vpssim.com) — kinda like CentminMod but from Vietnam (Docs are limited)
7. [HocVPS](https://hocvps.com) — also kinda like CentminMod and also from Vietnam